# Add speed limit to road segments

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro

I possess a line shapefile that represents a road network, along with a route event table that contains speed limits for specific route segments. My goal is to integrate the speed limit data into the shapefile. While attempting to visualize the route events, I observed that not every road in the shapefile has corresponding speed limit data in the table. How can I retain all the features in the shapefile and supplement them with the available speed information?

Comment: join by id? if both files have a common id.